# Displayed data in pivot table is not the same as the excel spreadsheet or the detailed view

Tags: excel

My Excel spreadsheet and the detailed view (click on the numbers in the table) are the same but display in the table is different.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas on what? Sorry, I am not able to follow at all what you are describing. Can you please make it more clear or share a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the title of the question, I believe you are referring to the number format of your pivot table. If this is the case, please click on the field in your field list then on "Value field settings...". on the pop up, click on the button in the lower left corner marked "Number format" which will bring up yet another pop up that will let you format the numbers however you like (number, currency, date, or custom).